# Creating nested virtual directories in IIS 7.5 \ C# (.NET v4.0)

Tags: c#, iis-7, virtual-directory

I created a Windows Service, with a constant interval that checks few lines in the DB, and creates virtual directories in the IIS by code.

Those virtual directories are created in the following template:

`"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/" + vdName`

As written, virtual directories are created successfully, but in the ROOT folder of my website in IIS.

MY GOAL, is to create those virtual directories, whithin subfolders of my other web-application.

What should be the correct path? I guess it should be something like the following:

`"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/Root/[AnotherVirtualDir]/subDir1/subDir2/" + vdName`

But this offcourse, doesn't work :)

(.NET v4.0, IIS 7.5, Windows 2008 R2)

Thanks in advance!

Gal.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a Site with some tree of directories where the virtual directories are leaves on the tree.

If your web files are located at '/ROOT/' you can have multiple IIS sites pointing to different folders.  Lets take Site1 as an example.

```
/Root/Site1/
```

This site can have an array of folders.

```
/Root/Site1/Sub1/
/Root/Site1/Sub2/
```

You can then put your virtual directories in those.

```
/Root/Site1/Sub1/VirtualDir1/
/Root/Site1/Sub1/VirtualDir2/
/Root/Site1/Sub2/VirtualDir3/
/Root/Site1/Sub2/VirtualDir4/
```

You can do a similar structure in a separate site.  Having a site with a virtual directory is very similar to nested virtual directories.

The objective is to avoid nested virtual directories by using plain sub-directories or multiple sites.